# Google content api for shopping using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I needed to develop a ruby on rails (rails 3.2) solution to connect with Google content api for shopping.

I tried to search on google but I couldn't find any rails gem for it or any good info how to do this.

Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Thanks so much in advance.